# Using jQuery, how do you select an element that is a child of $(this)?

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, this

Rough HTML structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Assuming I have a function like this:

```
$('div.wrapper').each(function() {
    // more stuff
});
```

I basically want to do things like:

```
$(this).('p:eq(2)').remove();
```

*or*

```
$(this).('p:contains("old text")').text('new text');
```

Starting with `$(this)` I just want to select child elements inside of it.

Comment: Use it as context like `$('p', this)` or use `find()` like `$(this).find('p')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('div.wrapper').each(function() {
    $('p:eq(2)', this).remove();
});
```

which uses `this` as the container or parent relative to the element you want to find.

or

```
$('div.wrapper').each(function() {
    $(this).find('p').eq(2).remove();
});
```

which uses `.find()` to do the same thing as above.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tvJ6e/)**

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I hadn't yet understood that you could use a context, as you demonstrated in your first example.

Using that same first example, what would you suggest to be the easiest way to include a method of only targeting the wrapper DIVs after but not including the first one? I tried `:gt(0)` and `.slice()` with no luck.

Comment: If you mean to do something to the divs but not the first one, you could add `.not(':first')` to the end. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tvJ6e/1/

Comment: Apologies. I meant to ignore the first div and then only look for items inside of the 2nd and onward.

Comment: Ah, well that's just as easy. Use `$('div.wrapper').not(':first')`  or `$('div.wrapper:gt(0)')` instead of `$('div.wrapper')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.wrapper p').eq(1).remove();
```

.find() is another method you could lookup.

Answer (score 0):

to get only the children of `$(this)` you can use:

```
$(this).children();
```